# An expression for positioning an element

Tags: after-effects

I’ve got a problem with creating a proper expression when it comes to a position of an image.
I do have this expression placed in position: thisComp.layer("TA1").transform.position

My goal is adding to this expression (thisComp.layer("TA1").transform.position)
An extra line which can move the whole image by 200 pixels down

I don’t know what to type in order to make it work or how to solve it. I’ve tried to do my research on expressions but so far unable to find any answers myself.

Thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyQIE.jpg)

Comment: you want to move it 0 pixels across, and 200 pixels down. So, use `thisComp.layer("TA1").transform.position - [0, 200]`. This is very basic expressions, I'm wondering what research you've actually done.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Stib's comment above (I still don't have enough rep to comment). You can use the pickwhip tool to access the individual x and y properties. The pickwhip tool is the one with the spiral icon below the property values.

If I click on the pickwhip and drag it to the x value of my position, I get:

```
temp = transform.position[0];
[temp, temp]
```

If I then add a line between those and pickwhip the y value, I'll have:

```
temp = transform.position[0];
transform.position[1]
[temp, temp]
```

Then I can change it to:

```
x = transform.position[0];
y = transform.position[1] + 200;
[x, y]
```

This should also give you what you want.

Of course this could also be done to a seperate layer giving you:

```
x = thisComp.layer("TA1").transform.position[0];
y = thisComp.layer("TA1").transform.position[1] + 200;
[x, y]
```